# How to set properties of userform inside function

Tags: vba

On the UserForm_Activate() code, I want to call a function (which has not been created yet) that will set scroll properties of the Userform. See code below.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
MakeFormResizable 
End Sub
```

On the Modules4 sheet, I have the following code:

```
Public Sub MakeFormResizable()
    Me.ScrollHeight = .Height
    Me.ScrollWidth = .Width
End Sub
```

When I run the code that I have pasted, I get the error "Compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference."

Answer (score 1):

It will not work as `Me` is local ….

Perhaps you want to pass the Userform object to a Public sub, as follows:

```
Public Sub MakeFormResizable(ByRef aUserform As MSForms.UserForm)

With aUserform
    'Do your stuff
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim MyObject
Set MyObject = Me
MakeFormResizable MyObject 
End Sub

Public Sub MakeFormResizable(MyObject)
With MyObject
.ScrollHeight = .Height
End If
End With
End Sub
```